# im making a purge command for my discord bot but it aint working i intend it to

Tags: node.js

im trying to make a purge command for my discord bot in node.js but everytime it removes one less than it should do(cus the bot thinks the message i send is also one of the messages i want 2 delete) but when i try to do some simple math to just make the number one higher i get something like this:
10 + 1 = 101 at least that is what the code does this is the code for the purge command i currently use:

```js
  const args = msg.content
    .slice(prefix.length)
    .trim()
    .split(" ");
   const Args2 = args[2];
   const DeleteAmount = Args2;
   if (!args[2]) return msg.channel.send("Please Specify a amount");
   if (args[2] > 100) return msg.channel.send("You cant delete a amount higher than 100")
   if (args[2] < 1) return msg.channel.send("You cant delete less than one message")
  msg.channel.bulkDelete(DeleteAmount);
  msg.channel.send(`${DeleteAmount} messages have been deleted`);
 } else if(msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}PurgeTest`)) {
 msg.channel.send("You Do not have Permission to delete messages");
 msg.channel.send("Only people with the role CustomBotAdmin can delete messages");
 }
```

sorry for the messy text...

edit: ah i got it fixed

Comment: Please just format your text/code/question, rather than apologize for it.

Comment: nah............